# Java how to write _ with Robot class

Tags: java, keypress, awtrobot, keyrelease

I use the robot class in my Java Code. I want to press the key "_" but the keycode 189 doesn't work for the Code

```
public void type() throws Exception

Robot rob = new Robot();

rob.keyPress(189);
rob.keyRelease(189);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way is to use `SHIFT` + `-`.

```
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

It seems that on a French keyboard following code would work, as the keyboard as a designated underscore key:

```
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
```

From [this](https://www.thelocal.fr/20160120/what-annoys-expats-the-most-about-the-french-keyboard) source they say:

> Numbers are not prioritized
>
> Writing the numbers on a French keyboard requires using the shift key each time.
>
> That means the AZERTY keyboard prioritizes things like the accented letters (such as é) and brackets - and even the ampersand (&) over numbers.

[image]

Looking at the `8` key, you can find the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the keyboard layout not having an actual underscore key. To get an underscore, you have to press Shift + - (minus).

```
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

[Source](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4474756)